# ViewDidAppear in main view not called when the modal view is dismissed how i can solve it?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

`viewDidAppear` in main view not called when the modal view is dismissed
how I can solve it?

[image: linked image: settings]

main view present view as kind present modally an as presentation overcurrent context then when I dismiss from second view back to main view ...  func `viewDidAppear` in main view  not called.

Comment: Set the presentation to something other than Over Current Context

Comment: To explain for @dan, the "main view" is *still* being displayed. Since "main" `viewDidAppear` once and is presenting something modally, all dismissing that modal view does is, well, dismiss that view and the view behind it - which already appeared - is back in view.